# Twitter Live feed sometimes not work

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have show my twitter live feed in my site using following code:

```
<div id='twitter_div'>                        
    <ul id='twitter_update_list'>       
    </ul>                             
</div>
```

JS

```
http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?exclude_replies=true&screen_name=MY_TWITTER_ID&callback=twitterCallback2&count=2
```

And also tried below  `javascript` URL also but not work.

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/MY_TWITTER_ID.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1
```

But sometimes this not load the twitter feed and it shows blank div. Do I need to update or change those URL or and more `javascript` need?

Comment: have a look at the following link....may be you need to update your twitter feed url according to this tutorial.  http://www.kristarella.com/2009/01/display-your-tweets-without-a-plugin/

Comment: Firstly, can  you post your actual JS? Secondly, are you just hitting the rate limit? Thirdly, are you aware that v1 of the API will cease to work at all very soon (March 5th 2013)? When that happens, you'll need to upgrade to v1.1 which requires OAuth and really needs to be done on the server. I've written [TweetServer](https://github.com/jamesallardice/tweetserver) to help people do this more easily.

Comment: @James Allardice 1.This is actual JS I used in my code. 2.Yes I want rate limit. 3. I aware that twitter API was updated but I have problem how to update my code according to Twitter API update.